# Navigate in reactjs only works with window.location.reload() . Why?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, navigation, location

I have a reactjs function , which on following each condition should navigate to different pages by setting state along with it.
example:

```
 navigate("/search", {
          state: {
            key: e.target.value.trim(),
            // publisherId: companyData?.companyId,
            publisherId: allData?.companyId,
          },
        });
```

I will provide the whole function below:

```
 const goToSearch = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      e.preventDefault();
      let role = localStorage.getItem("role");
      let switchRole = localStorage.getItem("switchRole");
      if (role === "ROLE_ADMIN") {
        if (switchRole === "licensee") {
          navigate("/licensee/search", {
            state: {
              key: e.target.value.trim(),
              licenseeId: localStorage.getItem("licenseeId"),
            },
          });
        } else if (switchRole === "channel") {
          navigate("/channel/search", {
            state: {
              key: e.target.value.trim(),
              channelId: localStorage.getItem("channelId"),
            },
          });
        } else if (switchRole === "user") {
          navigate("/user/search", {
            state: {
              key: e.target.value.trim(),
              publisherId: localStorage.getItem("customerId"),
            },
          });
        } else {
          navigate("/search", { state: { key: e.target.value.trim() } });
        }
      } else if (role === "ROLE_LICENSEE") {
        if (switchRole === "channel") {
          navigate("/channel/search", {
            state: {
              key: e.target.value.trim(),
              channelId: localStorage.getItem("channelId"),
            },
          });
        } else if (switchRole === "user") {
          navigate("/user/search", {
            state: {
              key: e.target.value.trim(),
              publisherId: localStorage.getItem("customerId"),
            },
          });
        } else {
          navigate("/search", {
            state: {
              key: e.target.value.trim(),
              // licenseeId: companyData?.companyId,
              licenseeId: allData?.companyId,
            },
          });
        }
      } else if (role === "ROLE_CHANNEL") {
        if (switchRole === "user") {
          navigate("/user/search", {
            state: {
              key: e.target.value.trim(),
              publisherId: localStorage.getItem("customerId"),
            },
          });
        } else {
          navigate("/search", {
            state: {
              key: e.target.value.trim(),
              // channelId: companyData?.companyId,
              channelId: allData?.companyId,
            },
          });
        }
      } else if (role === "ROLE_USER") {
        navigate("/search", {
          state: {
            key: e.target.value.trim(),
            // publisherId: companyData?.companyId,
            publisherId: allData?.companyId,
          },
        });
      }
      window.location.reload();
    }
  };
```

This function should be called on clicking enter on a InputBase. The code for it is given below:

```
 <Box
                flex={1}
                style={{
                  background: "#01537A",
                  alignItems: "center",
                  justifyContent: "center",
                }}
                sx={{
                  flexGrow: 1,
                  display: { xs: "flex", md: "flex" },
                }}
              >
                <Box
                  sx={{
                    maxWidth: { xs: "100%", md: "100%", lg: "720px" },
                    width: "100%",
                    fontSize: "34px",
                    display: "flex",
                    flex: "0 0 720px",
                  }}
                >
                  <Paper
                    component="form"
                    sx={{
                      display: "flex",
                      alignItems: "center",
                      width: "100%",
                      height: "38px",
                    }}
                  >
                    <IconButton sx={{ p: "10px" }} aria-label="menu">
                      <SearchIcon
                        style={{
                          color: "#01537A",
                        }}
                        sx={{
                          fontSize: { xs: "20px", md: "34px" },
                        }}
                      />
                    </IconButton>
                    <InputBase
                      width="100%"
                      style={{ ml: 1, flex: 1, color: "#373737" }}
                      placeholder={
                        localStorage.getItem("role") === "ROLE_USER" ||
                        pathname.includes("/user")
                          ? "Search for applications or users"
                          : "Search for apps, users or companies"
                      }
                     onKeyDown={goToSearch}
                        //  onKeyUp={goToSearch}
                      id="searchKey"
                      defaultValue={searchKey ? searchKey : ""}
                    ></InputBase>
                    <IconButton
                      sx={{ p: "10px" }}
                      aria-label="search"
                      onClick={clearData}
                    >
                      <CloseIcon
                        style={{
                          color: "#01537A",
                          transform: "rotate(90deg)",
                        }}
                        sx={{
                          fontSize: { xs: "20px", md: "34px" },
                        }}
                      />
                    </IconButton>
                  </Paper>
                </Box>
              </Box>
```

The problem i am facing is each navigate present in conditonal loop works only if there is :

```
 window.location.reload();
```

in the function. Using window.location.reload(), makes the page to simply reload all the time this makes it looks less pleasing . If i remove this window.location.reload(), none of the navigate work, but when i put consoles , in each conditional loops it actually gets inside the loop but navigate will never work.
Why does such a behaviour is seen anyone as any idea about it?

Comment: where does `navigate` come from?

Comment: navigate comes from :
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
  const navigate = useNavigate();

i beileve the problem is navigate is not getting reset with the new navigate path .It will only happen when window.location.reload takes place. So what i am looking for now is i want to trigger the navigate and undergo change without window.location.reload()

Comment: Perhaps the `InputBase` component is messing with your expected behaviour, when recreating your code in codesandbox (https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/beautiful-meninsky-nnsjws) it works as expected

Comment: ohhh okay.Let me check it , Thank you for your findings

Comment: I checked it by repalcing inputbase with textfield, and removing the window.location.reload(); from the function. But the issue still persists.At first it does navigate, but when i give different keywords in the search bar which will act as a payload to an api, it doesnt navigate nor any api call takes place .

Comment: could you provide a codesandbox (or github link) with your setup?

Comment: Yes,that will be better . Give me some time i will create one and comment it down.

Comment: [https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/zealous-lehmann-c5l8x6?file=%2Fsrc%2FchannelSearch.js%3A2%2C1-2%2C41] 
Can you check this codesandbox link and see if you need any additional info.
Thank you

Comment: with some alterations to quickly pick a role and switchrole it seems to be working on https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/happy-danilo-kycz9v

Comment: yes it is working in codesandbox. But i am not getting whats the issue with my code.

Comment: Heyy it worked for me. The fix i made was i added "searchkey" variable as a dependency for useeffect() which as the api for search results. 
Thank you so much for your responds.@Xiduzo